# Get a version from git tag inside post_commit script

Tags: bash, xcode-cloud

Working on CI and we would like to use tags from git for builds on Xcode Cloud.
So idea is that we make atag like "SOMESTRING-XXX.YYY.ZZZ-BUILDNUMBER.
Ok build number increments automatically with no problem, but getting the version number is kinda pain. My regex is a bit rusty.
Currently I have:

```
version=$(echo $IN | sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{0,4\}[0-9][^.]\).*/\1/p')
```

Which works ok for version format XXX.YYY.ZZZ, but fails when there is only one digit in last section ZZZ. Version sections could have up to 3 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got a solution:

```
version=$(echo $IN |  perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/')
```